# attempt to index global 'physics' (a nil value)

Tags: global, coronasdk, physics

I'm new with corona/lua and i'm i can't find a solution to this thing. I'm trying to spawn a object that fall from top to down and should stop at the bottom of the screen. Then i'll create the touch event etc etc..

but for now the problem is that i recieve this error:

attempt to index global 'physics' (a nil value)

and objects ofc doesn't fall down.

here is my code:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local buttonY = display.contentWidth * 0.02
local buttonWidth = display.contentWidth * 0.1
local buttonHeight = display.contentWidth * 0.1

background = display.newImage("graphics/background.jpg")

local localGroup = display.newGroup()
local spawnTable = {}

function spawnLattina(params)
    local object = display.newImage(params.image, params.buttonX,50);
    object.objTable = params.objTable;
    object.index = #object.objTable+1;
    object.name = "object:".. object.index;


    --fisica
    if params.hasBody then

        object.density = params.density or 0;
        object.friction = params.friction or 0;
        object.bounce = params.bounce or 0;
        object.isSensor = params.isSensor or false;
        object.bodyType = params.bodyType or "dynamic";
        print(object.density .. " Friction: ".. object.friction .."bodyType: "..object.bodyType)

        physics.addBody(object, object.bodyType, 
                {density = object.density, 
                friction = object.friction, 
                bounce = object.bounce}
        ) 
    end

    object.group = params.group or nil
    object.group:insert(object)
    object.objTable[object.index] = object


    return object
end

for i = 1, 2 do
    local spawns = spawnLattina(
        {
            image = "graphics/lattina.png",
            objTable = spawnTable,
            buttonX = math.random(50,480),
            hasBody = true,
            density = 0,
            friction = 12,
            bodyType = "static",
            group = localGroup,
        }
    )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't started the `physics engine`. Write the following lines on the top of your class:

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()
```

Keep Coding.................. :)